# Is browser console.log asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a lot of bugs in my react web app and it was hard to debug it because console.log was having a weird behavior, so i decided to replicate it in the simplest possible way.

Note that when the delete button is pressed, the console.log function is called before updating the object, but it shows the updated version, but when i use JSON.stringify it shows the real state at that point.

What the f is really happening right here? This makes no sense at all and it is difficulting debugging.

You can see it right here: [App](https://playcode.io/1515622)

Creating a copy of the array also doesnt work.
I just want a deep explanation.